# How to encrypt traffic from my laptop so that i can't be monitored over Wifi by any other on that network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, encryption, wifi-configuration

I would like to know what is the mechanism or tool to encrypt all traffic going or coming to my laptop which is connected to the wifi network so that i can't be monitored by anyone and no one on that network can track out what website i am visiting and so and so.My wifi network is 802.11g.

Comment: You could use a [VPN](https://proxpn.com/)

Answer (score 1):

An easy to use solution would be to use a managed VPN provider such as http://www.hidemyass.com/. It'll cost you a few $, but it's real easy to set up and more than secure enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Easy modo: pay for a private VPN. I use [Private Tunnel](https://www.privatetunnel.com/), there's also [ProXPN](https://proxpn.com/) which is free.

Normal mode: if you want privacy on public networks, you can set up a VPN concentrator at home, provided that you have a computer that can stay on 24/7. A quick and easy way of doing so is with a virtual machine running Vyatta Linux. You'll have to enter stuff on a command line but it's free and perfectly worth it.